# jQuery jsonp hide api key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Is there any way to use `jQuery.getJSON` without making the api key public? For example,

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://example.com/api/{API_KEY}/word', function(data) {
  // ...
});
```

Or is the only way to do this task on the backend?

Comment: You can obscure it, but that does not 100% mean hidden. Handling it on the server is far better. make an ajax request to your server, then get the contents on the server and send it back.

Comment: You could get the API key from another AJAX call, but the user could still see it if he's wise enough to use webkit inspector tools or firebug. Doing the call from a PHP page would be better (call the page and ask it to get the desired content to return to the client).

Comment: A method I've done is to setup a php template that a controller would call. In the template was the ajax call with key. Only this template never makes it to client. Instead, it's run on the backend then the HTML result is passed back to my controller which would then pass it to the view as HTML data in an ajax call from the view. Keep in mind, for one instance of this I had to incorporate a "polling" type loop till the changed HTML was returned to my controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide your api key with PHP. Create `something.php` that is:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/{API_KEY}/word');
    echo $data;
?>
```

The PHP runs server-side, so the client never sees your api key. Just use the local file such as:

```
jQuery.getJSON('something.php', function(data) {
// ...
});
```